# Why does my time delay for shooting bullets not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a delay every time you shoot in unity2d for my game. I used the `currentime += time.deltatime` and it seems to be working in the Debug.Log function, but it will not actually shoot. I can see in the inspector that they are not spawning, so this has nothing to do with the position.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public float delay = 3f;
    public float currentime = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(currentime);
        currentime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (currentime > delay)
            {
                currentime = 0;
                Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you assign the bullet Gameobject via inspector?

Comment: The code should work just fine. Make sure your `bullet` slot is assigned, and check your console for any errors.

Comment: it is assigned.

Comment: @DylanSantwani doesn the code enters `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))`?

Comment: it works if i do that

Comment: Are you assigning the bullet from scene or a prefab?

Comment: Is the Bullet assigned in the editor? Is the sprite on the correct Z level? Try putting some Log functions within your Bullet Object's Script

Comment: fixed it, it was 40 seconds in the editor